# Query error ambiguous column name 4 inner join table in SQL

Tags: mysql

I get an ambiguous column name error with this query . I can't figure out why. They all seem to be joined correctly so why doesn't SSMS know to display Cin_Expéditeur and Numéro_Agent and Cin_Destinataire?

Query:

```
SELECT 
    Cin_Expéditeur,
    Nom_Expéditeur,
    Prénom_Expéditeur,
    Phone_Expéditeur,
    Adresse_Expéditeur,
    Numero_Agent,
    Cin_Destinataire,
    Numero_Transfert,
    Code_Transfert,
    Montant_Transfert
FROM
    Expéditeur E
        INNER JOIN
    Transfert_Argent TA ON (E.Cin_Expéditeur = TA.CIN_Expéditeur)
        INNER JOIN
    Agent A ON (A.Numero_Agent = TA.Numero_Agent)
        INNER JOIN
    Destinataire D ON (D.Cin_Destinataire = TA.Cin_Destinataire)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: You are talking about SSMS, but tagged your question with [tag:mysql]. Are you working with MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: You select columns without telling the DB from which table. If a column name is present in 2 tables the DB does not know which one to take.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

All columns in the selct have point to a unique name, or you need to specify which table the column has to used.

For example your column Numero_Agent is minmum twice in your tables so you have to specify which table you want the column taken like TA.Numero_Agent

this goes for **every** column